# Using wpmail() as a conditional statement in Wordpress functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress, function, email, shortcode

I have 'Advanced Custom Fields' running on my Wordpress site and I want to trigger a notification based on a Select option being changed.

For example, if the 'Content Status' is changed to 'Collect' then an e-mail should be sent out. I managed to get this to work as a shortcode, so when I place this shortcode on the custom post type it works. However, it only sends the mail once per selection change.

So let's say the e-mail is sent when I select 'Collect' as an option. I then change the option to 'Delivered' and then back to 'Collect' again and it doesn't send the collect notification again. Am I missing something?

```html
// Shortcode to send mail based on Content Status being 'Collect'
function my_vc_shortcode_mail( $atts ) {


if ( get_field( 'content_status' )  == 'collect' ): ?>


<?php
add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'wpdocs_set_html_mail_content_type' );
 
$to = 'john@johndoe.com';
$subject = 'Time to collect your products';
$body = 'The email body content';
 
wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body );
 
// Reset content-type to avoid conflicts -- https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/23578
remove_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'wpdocs_set_html_mail_content_type' );
 
function wpdocs_set_html_mail_content_type() {
    return 'text/html';
}
?>

<?php endif;

}

add_shortcode( 'my_mail', 'my_vc_shortcode_mail');
```

Comment: This doesn't make any sense writing it as a shortcode.  You want to hook your function into the "save_post" hook and then check for the content status when it equals "collect"

Comment: Appreciate that buddy. I'm new to coding with php, do you have an example that may help?

Comment: Look at the WordPress save_post hook definition https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post

Comment: I've added an answer which shows you how to get the ACF field value for the post you have just saved and sends an email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go this will send a HTML formatted email when you save a post.

```
function user_collect_send_email( $post_id ) {

    if ( get_field( 'content_status', $post_id ) === 'collect' ):
        $to = 'john@johndoe.com';
        $subject = 'Time to collect your products';
        $body = 'The email body content';
        wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body );
    endif;
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'user_collect_send_email' );

function emails_set_content_type(){
    return "text/html";
}
add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'emails_set_content_type' );
```

Alternatively instead of setting the content type filter you can set each individual email format by setting the headers.

```
$headers[] = "Content-type: text/html";
wp_mail( $to, $subject, $body, $headers );
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is very helpful. Now I have to figure out how to set dynamic 'send to' value based on the ACF field for e-mail. <?php the_field( 'e-mail' ); ?>

Comment: @OmarChoudhry you're welcome. Just use the same format as I have shown for the content_status, $user_email = get_field( 'e-mail', $post_id );

Comment: Thanks so much, that's great and work :D Wish i could buy you a coffee or something lol. By the way, using the code above, I'm noticing that it's triggering the email anytime the post is updated, even if the content status isnt changed.

So if I edit the page content and leave the content status as is, it will still send the email if i update the post. Isn't there a way to limit it so that it only triggers the notification if the actual field is changed only

Comment: @OmarChoudhry I'm just helping out, people helped me when I first started so I'm just giving back :) Yes you can check for $_POST['content_status'] variable being set or not.  Not 100% sure this will work but it's something you can start with.  A better option in my option is to set a meta field to flag that you've already sent the email so it only gets sent the once.

Comment: Also you could be using the ACF hooks for saving data instead of the WordPress one. https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf-save_post/